# How to create a DataFrame from List?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to create DataFrame `df` that should look as simple as this:

```
+----------+----------+
| timestamp|      col2|
+----------+----------+
|2018-01-11|       123|
+----------+----------+
```

This is what I do:

```
val values = List(List("timestamp", "2018-01-11"),List("col2","123")).map(x =>(x(0), x(1)))    
val df = values.toDF    
df.show()
```

And this is what I get:

```
+---------+----------+
|       _1|        _2|
+---------+----------+
|timestamp|2018-01-11|
|     col2|       123|
+---------+----------+
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
val df = List(("2018-01-11", "123")).toDF("timestamp", "col2")
```

- `toDF` expects the input list to contain one entry per resulting Row
- Each such entry should be a case class or a tuple
- It does not expect column "headers" in the data itself (to name columns - pass names as arguments of `toDF`)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (sorry, I missed that you had the headers glued to each column).
Maybe something like this could work:

```
val values = List(
  List("timestamp", "2018-01-11"),
  List("col2","123")
)

val heads = values.map(_.head) // extracts headers of columns
val cols = values.map(_.tail) // extracts columns without headers
val rows = cols(0).zip(cols(1)) // zips two columns into list of rows
rows.toDF(heads: _*)
```

This would work if the "values" contained two longer lists, but it does not generalize to more lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the names of the columns statically you can use following syntax sugar

```
.toDF( columnNames: _*)
```

Where `columnNames` is the `List` with the names.